# Google Cloud Functions with a naked domain as the end point?

Tags: domain-name-system, google-cloud-platform

I'm using Google Cloud DNS which doesn't offer simple naked domain to WWW subdomain redirect. I want to use Cloud Functions instead of Google App Engine to do the 301 redirects.

Is this possible? Essentially I need a static IP for Cloud Functions and map the naked domain to the Cloud Function

P.S. Not interested in Heroku or Firebase

Comment: One possibility which suggests itself is [wwwizer](http://wwwizer.com/naked-domain-redirect).  Depending on your situation it might or might not be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid but it looks like Cloud Functions do not have static IP and are neither not supposed to.

Look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38811882/possible-to-get-static-ip-address-for-google-cloud-functions